# Should SignalR be in its own microservice

Tags: asp.net-web-api, architecture, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API and currently have SignalR inside the API. Is it better practice to have it out in its own microservice and have it communicate with the API? I believe this is a more adequate solution for the scalability of SignalR.

Please provide any sample projects that have the right architectural approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would say creating a service is the wait to go. Below is my implementation:

### Step 0: Optionally create a dictionary with Hub Functions for type safety

```
public static class HubFunctionStrings
{
    public const string SendNotification = "Notification";
}

public static class Constants
{
    public const string MyMessageHub = "/MyMessageHub";
}
```

### Step 1: Create a Hub conneciton and an Interface for it.

```
// The actual Registed
public class MyMessageHub : Hub<IMyMessageHub>
{

    [HubMethodName(HubFunctionStrings.SendNotification)]
    public async Task Message(string message, string lot = "")
    {
        await Clients.All.SendMessageAsync(message, lot);
    }
}

public interface IMyMessageHub
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a Notice to all the pages with Notification capabilities
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="lot"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HubMethodName(HubFunctionStrings.SendNotification)]
    Task SendMessageAsync(string message, string lot = "");
    
}
```

### Step 2: Register the Hub

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapHub<MyMessageHub>(Constants.MyMessageHub);
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
```

### Step 3: Create a Service & interface to invoke the Hub

```
// Service itself
public class SignalRService : ISignalRService
{
    #region Private Variables

    private IHubContext<MyMessageHub, IMyMessageHub> MyMessageHub { get; }

    #endregion Private Variables

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public SignalRService(IHubContext<MyMessageHub, IMyMessageHub> MyMessageHub)
    {
        // Create the connection hub connection
        MyMessageHub = MyMessageHub;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></paramm >
    public async Task SendNotificatinAsync(string message, string lot = "") =>
        await MyMessageHub.Clients.All.SendMessageAsync(message, lot);
        
}

// Interface for the service
public interface ISignalRService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Send a notificaiton
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="lot"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task SendNotificatinAsync(string message, string lot = "");
}
```

### Step 4: Register the service

```
// Add to Startup.cs
services.AddScoped<ISignalRService, SignalRService>()
```

### Step 5: Usage from API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    private ISignalRService SignalRService { get; }

    public TestController(ISignalRService signalRService)
    {
        SignalRService = signalRService;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Send a notification
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="lot"></param>
    [HttpGet("SendNotification")]
    public async Task SendNotificationAsync(string message, string lot = "") =>
        await SignalRService.SendNotificatinAsync(message, lot);
}
```

Comment: So If I understood you correctly, you create a Web API project which contains all SignalR stuff, and then all other services call this SignalR service over HTTP to make use of SignalR?  Is this scalable?

Comment: @killswitch yes